# Subversion missing as a version control option in PhpStorm

Tags: svn, phpstorm

I'm trying to configure Subversion in PhpStorm 2017.1 and there is no option for it under Version Control as the docs suggest (`File | Settings | Version Control | Subversion`). This is what I see

[image: Screen shot from settings]

Any ideas on what I'm missing. I have tortoiseSVN with command line tools installed and I've even tried installing SilkSVN.

Comment: Please check that `Subversion Integration` plugin is installed and enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`

Comment: Thanks That was it. I didn't know it had a separate plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for each VCS comes as a separate plugin.

Please ensure that **Subversion Integration plugin** is installed and enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Settings > plugins > 
Search for subversion then click subversion integration, then Apply & ok
[image]

Comment: OK, The UI changed for the worse. I verified the plugin was installed. Still no SVN option in lists. You now have to click the tab labeled 'Installed', then find the plugin and check the box. First tab you see it suggests it's installed but it is not!

Answer (score 1):

What [ficuscr suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056833/subversion-missing-as-a-version-control-option-in-phpstorm#comment98074965_49850795) worked for me.

> OK, The UI changed for the worse. I verified the plugin was installed. Still no SVN option in lists. You now have to click the tab labeled 'Installed', then find the plugin and check the box. First tab you see it suggests it's installed but it is not!

File -> Settings -Plugins -> Search for Subversion.

Select it and goto Installed Tab. And make sure to enable the plugin.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKUaN.png]